# Characters in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java

I am currently a week into learning Java, and I am doing a tic tac toe game. Almost everything is perfect, except for the fact that I don't know how to change 1's and 2's into X's and O's. My professor told us that we cannot change the main method. 0 represents a space, 1 represents an X, and 2 represents an O.

```
public static void printBoard(int[][] board) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (j == 2) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] );
            } else {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] +  "  |");
            }
        }   
    }
```

}

Comment: Look into your `printBoard` method. See that it is responsible for the visual representation of the inner data of your class. What that means is, however you store the data (ones and zeroes and batman signs and whatever else you want), you only have to modify `printBoard` to see a change in the visual output the user sees. Specifically, look at the `print` method. It'll print a numeric value. Well, why not assign the numeric value to a variable, check to see if it's a `1` or `0`, and print out some character depending? That would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to create a method which converts a number to the character it represents, like below:

```
public static char toText(int num) {
    switch (num) {
        case 0: return ' ';
        case 1: return 'X';
        case 2: return 'O';
        default: return '?';
    }
}
```

And then you can use this method when printing your board. This would avoid having to change the way you internally represent your board:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (j == 2) {
            System.out.print(toText(board[i][j]) );
        } else {
            System.out.print(toText(board[i][j]) +  "  |");
        }
}
```